# ralink rt2860 not working anymore in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 12.10, ralink

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10, however, my network card is not working anymore. When I had 12.04 installed, I just had to download the driver from Ralink, go to the directory and enter:

`make`

`sudo make install`

This made my network card work.  When I try to do this in 12.10, it seems like it works, but it doesn't. I can enable the module, it recognizes the network card, but I am unable to connect to any wireless network.

How can I get my wireless card working again?

If anyone knows a solution, please tell me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source rt2800pci module should work with your card for all the 12.x+ releases.  Deinstall the vendor's rt2860sta module (or whatever it's called), check that no "blacklist rt2800pci" line is present in any file in /etc/modules.d, and you should have a working wireless.  The rt2800pci module is present in the default installation, and is even present on the live media.  Wireless should work out of the box for you.